# WebView is null in PushPlugin

Tags: push-notification, cordova-2.7.0

I am using PhoneGap pushnotification for Android but in gWebView and gECB I am getting null:

```
if (gECB != null && gWebView != null) {
    Log.v(TAG, "PushPlugin-sendJavascript: " + _d);
    gWebView.sendJavascript(_d);
}
```

I am using `gWebView = this.webView;` to get the the current view.

Cordova 2.9
Android Version for debugging - 4.1.2
Plugin - PushPlugin